# Is it possible to join a closed group through a javascript graph api on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does facebook javascript api support the functionality of sending requests to join groups? I'm making a closed group for my organisation, so everything is pulled from facebook and displayed on our intranet but only if you are a member of that group. I had a request that I should make a functionality of requesting to join a facebook group using the api and not on facebook, as employee are not allowed to see the facebook website unless the specified urls, can someone please let me know if this is possible to do and if maybe you know of some link that I can go a look at. Please let me know, even the iframe will do at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry can't find anything in the Javascript API that allows you to send invites to groups.